# How can I extract HTML table data using Perl?

Tags: html, perl

I need to retrieve some data from a web page. After analysing the HTML code of the page, I found the data I need is embeded in a table with a unique table id. I don't know whether it is an HTML rule or not, anyway it's very good for parsing I think.

The data in the table is  arranged as below (various attributes and tags have been omitted in order to give you a clear "data structure")

```
<table .... id = "tablename" .... >
    <tr>
         <td .... >filed1</td>
             ....
         <td .... >filedn</td>
    </tr>
         #several "trs" here
    <tr>
         <td .... >filed1</td>
             ....
         <td .... >filedn</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So my question is how to use Perl's HTML parser utility to meet my needs in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TableExtract) sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HTML::Table](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Table).

Answer (score -1):

Look at Ken MacFarlane's [Parsing HTML with HTML::Parser](http://www.ddj.com/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=199101946&queryText=start) in *The Perl Journal*.  I'm not sure if that's the parser you're referring to, but it looks like it can do what you want, or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: You shouldn't have to reach down into HTML::Parser for this. There are many tools built on top of it that should be able to handle the job.